# Options menu not showing up in Android

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

My objective is to you use one menu for all activities. For that, I have a base activity which consists of 2 methods: `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()`. In `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, I am creating a menu using `MenuInflater`.

Further, I have 2 activities which extends the above `BaseActivity` so that same menu is shown for both the activities. My issue is that, when my first activity is launched, options menu is shown, I move to second activity from the first. In the second activity also, when I press the menu button, I am able to view the menu. After that, using <kbd>Back</kbd> key press, I come to first activity again, the menu is also shown up there, But when I move to the second activity thereafter, **menu is not shown to me.**

Comment: I am just using Menu Inflater and inflating menu in onCreateOptionsMenu.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post code of your Base Activity's onOptionsItemSelected and onCreateOptionsMenu?

Anyway, with no code available. And not enough clarity, I assume that the following will work for you...

add `@Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
     }`

to your base activity

Comment: I am just using Menu Inflater and inflating menu in onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: does it look like this? - `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }`

Comment: is onCreateOptionsMenu even being called when you navigate to the 2nd activity again?

Comment: When i navigate to the 2nd activity for the first time, the onCreateOptionsMenu is being called and i am able to see the menu, but when i navigate for the second time, the menu is not being shown. That's the issue.

Comment: okay well, unless I see code I cant do much but... trythis: add `@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {finish(); } to the base activty

Comment: The 2 activities are in an activity group.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum SDK version could be the cause. If you reduce it to 13-, you should probably see the menu show up again. Good article on this subject: [POST](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)